# connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed on Macos

Tags: database, postgresql, macos, localhost, tableau-cloud

I created postgresql data base. Then i am trying to connect it to different BI technologies, but nothing works. Here is the error "**connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Connection timed out
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?**".

I use Postgresql app on my MacOS M1 and i am trying to connect to Tableau.
Help please!

I've checked if there is a **firewall** turned on, but its not.
Also i've tried "**postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres**", but this doesnt work too...

***Upd1***: I installed Tableau on my Mac and only then Tableau connected to the postgresql data base. I still dont understand why all this happens? Why i cant connect it through the Internet?

***Upd2***: I have tried to change postgresql.conf. I uncommented line "listen_addresses" and "port", and restarted postgresql with "brew services restart postgresql". Also i have changes pg_hba.conf and now it is like that [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTrPD.png)

***Upd3*** Problem solved. You cant connect from online tableau to localhost data base:)